# Open folder dialog freeze (JetBrains Products)

Tags: jetbrains-ide

I have a problem with JB Products last 4 months. When I'm trying to open new project, open dialog nothing loads and when I want to close them it's freezes. After a long freeze dialog finally closes and when I reopen it - it momentally loads all folder structures. Anyone have this problem and how you solve it?

Dialog freeze:

[image: Dialog freeze]

GoLand latest version:

[image: GoLand latest version]

Dialog after reload:

[image: Dialog after reload]

*Sorry for my bad English*

Comment: Check your idea.log file (`Help | Show Log in Explorer`) for possible exceptions and related entries in the log when this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any slow/disconnected network shares? DVD drives that fail to open? Such 'black holes' can cause problems building the directory tree.

We plan to re-work the file chooser dialog to avoid such issues, see [IDEA-101218](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-101218); please vote/watch it to be notified on updates.

Comment: Нет, у меня нет таких устройств. В сети есть только роутер и мой компьютер. Дисковода нет вообще. Раньше такой проблемы не наблюдал, появилась неожиданно при обновлении на 2019.2 всех продуктов JetBrains.

No, I don’t have such devices. There is only a router and my computer on the network. There is no drive at all. I did not observe such a problem before, it appeared unexpectedly when updating to 2019.2 all JetBrains products.

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer on Jetbrains bug tracker that will probably help a lot. If you use Windows Subsystem Linux, then perhaps this is the reason for freezes. In order to get rid of this, go to the `Action Menu` (`Ctrl+Shift+A`) and find the `Experimental Features`. There disable `wsl.p9.show.roots.in.file.chooser`. That's all!

Comment: you should have mentioned in your question that you were using WSL